# Lucene filter with docIds

Tags: filter, lucene

I'm trying to do the following: I want to create a set of candidates by querying each field separately and then adding the top k matches to this set. After I'm done with that, I need to run another query on this candidate set. 
The way how I implemented it right now is using a QueryWrapperFilter with a BooleanQuery that matches the unique id field of each candidate document. However, this means I have to call IndexSearcher.doc().get("docId") for each candidate document before I can add it to my BooleanQuery, which is the major bottleneck. I'm only loading the docId field via MapFieldSelector("docId).

I wanted to create my own Filter class, but I can't use the internal Lucene doc ids directly, because they are specified per segment. Any thoughts on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reading the stored docId, index the field (it probably already is) and use the [FieldCache](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FieldCache.html) to retrieve docIds much faster.  Then instead of using the docIds in a BooleanQuery, try using a [TermsFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/contrib-queries/org/apache/lucene/search/TermsFilter.html) or [FieldCacheTermsFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FieldCacheTermsFilter.html).  The latter documentation describes the performance trade-offs.

Comment: I used the FieldCache along with the FieldCacheTermsFilter and things are running now much faster, thanks!