# Lucene: Filter query by doc ID

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene, full-text-search, text-mining

I want to have in the search response only documents with specified doc id. In stackoverflow I found this question ([Lucene filter with docIds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627655/lucene-filter-with-docids)) but as far as I understand there is created the additional field in the document and then doing search by this field. Is there another way to deal with it?

Comment: why you don't want to create an additional field while creating the index?

Comment: @WasiAhmad I was thinking about reusing docid, but following to the answer to my question I realized that it's not so good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lucene's docids are intended only to be internal keys. You should not be using them as search keys, or storing them for later use. Those ids are subject to change without warning. They will be changed when updating or reindexing documents, and can change at other times, such as segment merges, as well.

If you want your documents to have a unique identifier, you should generate that key separate from the docId, and index it as a field in your document.